# How to move function from onBindViewHolder to ViewHolder

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

I'm having some issues with my button(it is not working as it is supposed to), where the `onClickListener` of that button is located inside `onBindViewHolder`. as shown below:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <SearchAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final User user = mUsers.get(position);
holder.btn_follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.btn_follow.getText().toString().equals("follow"))
                {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(user.getId()).setValue(true);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                            .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                    addNotifications(user.getId());
                }
                else
                {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(user.getId()).removeValue();
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                            .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                    // FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(user.getId()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

I want to move my `OnClickListener` from `onBindViewHolder` to `ViewHolder`. However, I don't know how to replace this line  `final User user = mUsers.get(position);` because there is no position in ViewHolder. I tried `getAdapterPosition()` but then my app crashed.

how can I move `onClickListener` to `ViewHolder` the right way?